# Rails params "method" isn't a method, is it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), the following example is given as a way to display what the server receives from a POST request:

```
def create
  render plain: params[:article].inspect
end
```

In the subsequent description, the text states

> The params method is the object which represents the parameters (or fields) coming in from the form. The params method returns an ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess object.

While I understand that all methods are objects, I don't understand how it's correct to refer to the params object as a method. Specifically, the phrase "returns an ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess object" suggests to me that there are two calls going on--what in python might look like:

```
params().__getitem__('article')
```

but I don't think that's what's actually going on.

The [conversation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blame/master/guides/source/getting_started.md) around those lines also refers to params as a method, so I'm starting to think I must be missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm new to Ruby, and while I understand that all methods are objects,

No, they aren't. Methods belong to objects (more precisely: methods are defined in modules, and executed in the context of objects), but they are not, by themselves, objects. (It is, however, possible to obtain a reflective proxy which represents the concept of a method by calling the `method` method, which returns a `Method` object.)

> I don't understand how it's correct to refer to the params object as a method.

Because it is a method. Not an object.

What else would it be? Syntactically, it's obvious that it can only be one of three things: a keyword, a variable, or a method call.

It can't be a keyword, because Rails is just a Ruby library, and Ruby libraries can't change the syntax of the language (e.g. add or remove keywords). It can't be a variable, because in order for it to be parsed as a variable, the parser would need to have seen an assignment to it within the same block.

Ergo, the only thing it can *possibly* be, is a method call. You don't even need to know anything about Rails to know this. It's just basic Ruby syntax 101.

> Specifically, the phrase "returns an ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess object" suggests to me that there are two calls going on--what in python might look like:
>
> ```
> params().__getitem__('article')
> ```
>
> but I don't think that's what's actually going on.

That is exactly what is going on. You call the method `params` and then you call the method `[]` on the object that is returned by calling the method `params`.

This is in no way different from `foo.bar`: you call `foo`, then call `bar` on the return value of `foo`.

Comment: But if you have an object List with a method length, and you call List.length.is_a?(Object), that returns true, right?

Comment: @tasteslikelemons Yes, but that calls `is_a?(Object)` on the return value of `List.length` (what would be most likely an integer value).

Comment: Indeed. In fact, if you call `some_list.length.is_a?(Integer)`, that will also return `true`. Now, would you conclude from that that methods are integers?

Answer (score 2):

The `params` method is a method, returns a hash (which holds some details about parameters send to the app). Simplified it looks like this:

```
def fake_params
  { :controller => 'foo', :action => 'bar' }
end
```

You can call another method directly on the returned hash like this:

```
fake_params[:action]    #=> 'bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

`params` is a *method* defined in `ActionController::Metal` which returns the `request.parameters` object.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L140